# 'mongodump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backup

Here I am going to back up my MongoDB **Atlas** database on my **MERN** project. I use the below code to backup, but this message shows when I run the express server. First create mongodb_backup.js, cron.js and require the server.js file. These are all working fine. 
And one thing that is the correct URL to give to the dbOptions.host.

**mongodb_backup.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('lodash');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
const path = require('path');
const backupDirPath = path.join(__dirname, 'database-backup/');

var dbOptions = {
    user: '****',
    pass: '****',
    host: 'mongodb+srv://cluster0-gtick.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    port: 27017,
    database: 'Project-Management',
    autoBackup: true,
    removeOldBackup: true,
    keepLastDaysBackup: 2,
    autoBackupPath: backupDirPath
};
exports.stringToDate = dateString => {
    -------------------- all works fine
};
exports.empty = mixedVar => {
    ------------------------all works fine
};
// Auto backup function
exports.dbAutoBackUp = () => {
    if (dbOptions.autoBackup == true) {
        let date = new Date();
        let beforeDate, oldBackupDir, oldBackupPath;
        currentDate = this.stringToDate(date);
        let newBackupDir = ------;

        let newBackupPath = dbOptions.autoBackupPath + '-mongodump-' + newBackupDir;
        if (dbOptions.removeOldBackup == true) {
            -------------all works fine          
        }

        // Command for mongodb dump process
        let cmd =
            'mongodump --host ' +
            dbOptions.host +
            ' --port ' +
            dbOptions.port +
            ' --db ' +
            dbOptions.database +
            ' --username ' +
            dbOptions.user +
            ' --password ' +
            dbOptions.pass +
            ' --out ' +
            newBackupPath;

        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (this.empty(error)) {
                // check for remove old backup after keeping # of days given in configuration.
                if (dbOptions.removeOldBackup == true) {
                    if (fs.existsSync(oldBackupPath)) {
                        exec('rm -rf ' + oldBackupPath, err => { });
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log(stderr); //here consoling the error
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: MongoDB tools are installed separately from server, sounds like you haven't installed them.

Comment: @D. SM can you tell me how to install them

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/